# How to run the entire code in a .sql file using Rstudio?

Tags: r, sql-server-2012

I have a dynamic code in a .sql file implementing which is kinda hard using RSQLite sqldf.
Can we do something that runs the entire code in SQL Server itself ? The only thing that happens through R is the activation of the code and the transfer of the first major dataset that into the SQL Server.

I have seen

```
           sqlQuery()
```

and

```
            sqldf()
```

But have not found any way to actually run the entire .sql file in SQL Server itself

Thanks

Comment: You could make a simple connection between SQL server and R with help of the RODBC package. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/214510788-Setting-up-R-to-connect-to-SQL-Server-

Comment: Make an example to illustrate the problem. What do you mean by "a dynamic code"? Do you just want to use the DBI package to connect to a SQL Server database?